# Using track metadata from audio shortcode

Tags: audio

How can i add an audio track in the editor and then access its metadata.
When you upload the audio track before inserting it you can fill in Artist info, track name, album and description.
Is there a way you can access that info to, for example, be able to output a metadata caption. Something like.

Audio Player.
*Sting - Fields of gold - 1991.*

Is it posible with shortcode attributes? like:

`[audio scr="http://mywebsite.com/mytrack.mp3" title="The Title" artist="Artist" Album="album"]`
??

Any other way to access it?

Comment: when you say access it, what do you mean? Can you describe the end goal rather than the process?

Comment: Question updated. Sorry, I wasn't very clear.

Comment: you want to access the attributes of the shortcode?

Comment: No, I want to add a metadata text to the audio player. But I as long as I read it's not possible. The thing is the playlist isn't working for some reason, there you have artist, track, album info.

Comment: to the audio player? playlist? please try to explain by steps of what you are trying to accomplish, saying audio then playlist its confusing, also the `metadata` you talk about its the one for the audio shortcode, or for the audio file, everything has `metadata` @_@

Comment: I mean that If I need the title and the artist to be outputted together with the player , it's probably easier to use the playlist option, not audio. 
BUT the playlist isn't working for some reason as I explain here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/281147/playlist-doesnt-work
But this question is about audio, not playlist. Question is how can we output the audio's metadata, the one we fill in when we upload the file (name, artist, album, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you can access that data using [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/), remember that almost everything in WordPress is a type of a post, an `audio` its a `wp_attachment` type, you just need the `ID`, also you can make a `shortcode`, this is an example:

```
function my_audio_func($atts) {
    $audio_id = $atts['id']; //we need an ID as attribute
    //we get the audio and the metadata
    $metadata = get_post_meta($audio_id, "_wp_attachment_metadata");
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($metadata);
    echo "</pre>";

    //we get the post object to get the URL of the AUDIO
    $audio = get_post($audio_id);
    $audio_src = $audio->guid;//for object values is like this is an object
    //
    $attr = array(
        'src' => $audio_src,
        'loop' => '',
        'autoplay' => '',
        'preload' => 'none'
    );
    //display the audio player
    echo wp_audio_shortcode($attr);
    echo "<br/>";
    //display the metadata ARTIST
    echo $metadata[0]["artist"];//for metadata like this is an array
}

add_shortcode('my_audio', 'my_audio_func');
```

in your post use it like this:

```
[my_audio id="198"]
```

it will show like this:

[image]

this is all the metadata keys, the info you can get:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(16) {
    ["dataformat"]=>
    string(3) "mp3"
    ["channels"]=>
    int(2)
    ["sample_rate"]=>
    int(44100)
    ["bitrate"]=>
    int(128000)
    ["channelmode"]=>
    string(12) "joint stereo"
    ["bitrate_mode"]=>
    string(3) "cbr"
    ["lossless"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["encoder_options"]=>
    string(6) "CBR128"
    ["compression_ratio"]=>
    float(0.090702947845805)
    ["fileformat"]=>
    string(3) "mp3"
    ["filesize"]=>
    int(458918)
    ["mime_type"]=>
    string(10) "audio/mpeg"
    ["length"]=>
    int(29)
    ["length_formatted"]=>
    string(4) "0:29"
    ["artist"]=>
    string(6) "MY_ARTIST"
    ["album"]=>
    string(5) "MY_ALBUM"
  }
}
```

if you want the caption or name, that would be in the post object:

```
object(WP_Post)#587 (24) {
  ["ID"]=>
  int(198)
  ["post_author"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["post_date"]=>
  string(19) "2017-09-26 15:54:30"
  ["post_date_gmt"]=>
  string(19) "2017-09-26 15:54:30"
  ["post_content"]=>
  string(38) ""My test audio"."
  ["post_title"]=>
  string(35) "My test audio"
  ["post_excerpt"]=>
  string(10) "MY_CAPTION"
  ["post_status"]=>
  string(7) "inherit"
  ["comment_status"]=>
  string(4) "open"
  ["ping_status"]=>
  string(6) "closed"
  ["post_password"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_name"]=>
  string(35) "my-test-audio"
  ["to_ping"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["pinged"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_modified"]=>
  string(19) "2017-09-26 17:36:59"
  ["post_modified_gmt"]=>
  string(19) "2017-09-26 17:36:59"
  ["post_content_filtered"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_parent"]=>
  int(176)
  ["guid"]=>
  string(97) "http://my_testsite.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2017/03/my-test-audio.mp3"
  ["menu_order"]=>
  int(0)
  ["post_type"]=>
  string(10) "attachment"
  ["post_mime_type"]=>
  string(10) "audio/mpeg"
  ["comment_count"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["filter"]=>
  string(3) "raw"
}
```

i commented in the shortcode how you can access values in the object and in the metadata array.